# 'While' loop not continuing

Tags: c, while-loop

I am completely new to programming. I'm taking a class for C programming to replace another class in my engineering associate's degree because the professor for the required class left unexpectedly. Throughout the semester, we've been building a student report program as an ongoing project.

I'm writing a function to search for a student using their ID. Once the student is found, it displays the student's information. I've written a while loop to continue the search function until the user chooses to quit. Here's the code I've written for it:

```
while(continueSearch == true)
{
   
         FLUSH;
    //Prompt user for input
    printf("\nEnter student ID or ']' if finished searching: ");
    tempInput = getc(stdin);
    if(tempInput == ']')
    {
        FLUSH;
        printf("\nExiting student search\n");
        continueSearch = false;
        break;
    }
    else
        ungetc(tempInput, stdin);
        
    //ioResult = scanf("%d", &tempStudentID);
        
    //Verify user input is valid and flush buffer of invalid input
    if(scanf("%d", &tempStudentID) != 1)
    {
        printf("\aInvalid student ID. Student ID must be an integer. Please enter ID    again.\n");
        FLUSH;
    }//if
    //If user ID is not found
    else if(!(findStudID(studentID, numCurrStudents, tempStudentID, &index)))
    {
        printf("\n\aStudent ID was not found. Please enter a new ID.\n");
    }//else if
    //If user ID is found, display student data to screen   
    else if (findStudID(studentID, numCurrStudents, tempStudentID, &index))
    {
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t   STUDENT REPORT\n");
        printf("Last      First     ID      Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4   High    Low     Ave     Grade\n");
        printf("%-10s%-10s%-8.4d%-8d%-8d%-8d%-8d%-8d%-8d%-8.1f%-c\n", lastName[index], firstName[index], studentID[index], studentScores[index][0], studentScores[index][1], studentScores[index][2], studentScores[index][3], studentMaxScore[index], studentMinScore[index], studentAvg[index], studentLetterGrade[index]);tempStudentID = 1;
    }//else if
}
```

FLUSH is defined as:

```
#define FLUSH while (getchar () != '\n')
```

This was pulled directly from our textbook and what our professor suggested we use.

The loop is working as it should, except for under the 'if' section to check whether an integer was entered. If something other than an integer was entered, it will indicate that what was entered was invalid, but in order to continue with the loop, it requires hitting 'Enter' again after the invalid message is displayed. I can't figure out how to make it just loop back to the start without that extra 'Enter'.

Comment: PSA: `while (x == true)` can be reduced to just `while (x)`.

Comment: Do you have a separator for the numbers when entering them? If so, what is it?

Comment: How is your `FLUSH` macro defined? If that does anything like attempting to `fflush(stdin)` then you're in the Territory of Undefined Behaviour (and there be nasal demons).

Comment: This mixture of getc/ungetc/scanf/FLUSH(whatever this is) stuff looks fishy and terribly convoluted. You should tell us more about the requirements of this project.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the tip. As I said, I'm completely new to all of this. I'm not sure what a separator is.

Comment: @AdrianMole FLUSH is defined as #define FLUSH while (getchar () != '\n'). It's what was given to us in our textbook and what our professor advised that we use to flush the buffer.

Comment: ... and don't try to use `scanf` for validating input, it's a terrible idea and it will end in tears.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I took that directly from the suggested solution the professor gave us from the previous step of the project.

Comment: Aside: There is no need to call `findStudID` twice; the last `else if` can be changed to `else` because you already know the student was found at that point.

Comment: not sure what flush does here, but perhaps it forwards to the next record, and so you should flush only if all the input is correct., else repeat the inputs with a message invalid syntax warning or so.

Comment: An example of what @Jabberwocky said is if someone entered 567.89 as a student id, your design would accept that as a valid id of 567 rather than rejecting it as a non-integer. Similarly that code would accept 567A34ZQX as the integer 567. (They would leave stuff in the input stream which would foul up the next entry, except that you are constantly throwing away stuff from the input stream with your FLUSH macro.) How should your code react to such incorrect entries?

Comment: Unless you're working with individual digits you'll need a separator to know where one number stops and the next starts. A common choice is comma, space, or newline.

Comment: You should add the definition of FLUSH to your post. It is an important detail.

Comment: @AviBerger I just added it. But it's defined as #define FLUSH while (getchar () != '\n'). It was pulled directly from our textbook and what our professor suggested we use.

Comment: There's no need for the `continueSeach` variable, since you use `break` to stop the loop.

Comment: Your whole way of processing the input, with `getchar()` and `ungetc()`, is overly complicated. Read each line with `fgets()`. You can check if it begins with `]` first, then try to parse it as an integer with `sscanf()` or `strtol()`.

Comment: @Barmar We just got to strings and we have not gone over parsing strings. I took the getchar() and ungetc() from our professor. I think he used that because our virtual learning environment that simulates Linux was not allowing the user to input the EOF character while the program was running. I tried using that to end the search function and it would not accept 'Ctrl + d' at all.

Comment: I think it's time for you to learn to use a debugger, and step through the program to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Note how the provided FLUSH works & what it does. It is not "empty the input buffer" (which would be a conventional assumption, though wrong here); it is "read and discard input up to and including the next '\n'". Your symptom of needing an extra return entered could be the result of calling FLUSH when there is nothing in the input stream.

Comment: I think the problem is the `FLUSH` at the beginning of the loop. You're flushing once when the user types a non-number, then the loop restarts and you flush again. Each of these reads until it gets to a newline.

Comment: @AviBerger This is a beginning C programming class. We're still on a very basic level, so we're not required to take into account a lot of possible situations in user input that might come up. I'm pretty sure I could come up with a solution to the examples you gave, but it's not really expected at this point in time and would likely be ugly, as I probably don't have all the knowledge to make it a simpler solution.

Comment: @Barmar That was it. I took that out and it ran like it was supposed to. I might run up against some other problems, but it'll work for now to get my assignment turned in.

Comment: @AviBerger Thank you for that explanation. That made a lot more sense than how my professor explained it in class. Sometimes I can't wrap my head around exactly what the code is saying.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem here has to do with `FLUSH`, which waits for a newline. Suppose that you type `xxxx` as the input. It's not `']'`, so it makes it past the first if clause.

When it gets here:

```c
//Verify user input is valid and flush buffer of invalid input
if(scanf("%d", &tempStudentID) != 1)
{
    printf("\aInvalid student ID. Student ID must be an integer. Please enter ID    again.\n");
    FLUSH;
}
```

we see that `scanf` will not successfully find an integer. It prints the "Invalid" clause, eats the rest of the input (i.e. `xxx` and the terminating newline), and then proceeds.

This causes your enclosing while loop to restart. At the start of the while loop, we have

```c
while(continueSearch == true)
{
    FLUSH;
    // ...
}
```

So the first thing that happens is that `FLUSH` is called again. But now the input stream is empty, and a second `\n` is required to proceed.

This is why you need to hit `Enter` twice to proceed.

Comment: I'll also note a brief aside on asking questions here.
Very broadly, when asking for help here (which is exactly what this place is for, welcome to programming!), you'll get the best and fastest help if your question contains a complete minimally compiling example. For example, I would like to copy your program, compile it, and see what my compiler says about it. But you've given a snippet, and this isn't possible.